# printing an array with all hex numbers with n nibbles

Tags: c, nibble

I'm trying to code a program that does the following: "Receives an input (N) and outputs an array with all hexadecimals with `'N'` Nibbles on ascending order."

To do this, I created a main function

```
int main () {
int n;
printf("Insert number of N");
scanf(%d,&n)

outhexdecimals(N);

return(0);
}
```

the function outhexdecimals will create an array based on the input value of n, arrange it in asceding ordem and then outputs the array.

```
Ex: N = 3;
000 , 002, 003, 004, 005, ..., FFF
```

My problem is: I don't know how to convert the decimal number to hex, that is, after `'009'`, i do not know how to output the value `'00A'` on the array.

Is there a way that I can do this by converting the decimal value?

Any help provided in this matter is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: printf() will happily print in hex for you, just use "%03X" instead of "%d".

Comment: Think about how you convert numbers to a different base on pencil and paper.

Comment: Please explain how an input of "3" results in the shown desired output. For example, why is there no "001"?